# Toggle between layers in Carto Builder

Tags: carto, carto-js

If you publish a map with multiple layers using Carto Builder, is there a way for viewers of a map to toggle on/off a specific layer?

For example, imagine a choropleth map with a map marker overlay. While viewing both layers in tandem may be interesting. A user may also want to view just the underlying choropleth map without the overlay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to toggle layers on/off using CARTO Builder, all you have to do is acces the **Map Options** (the sliders icon under the pencil at the far left) and turn on *Layer Selector* in the checklist. Here's a screenshot showing how:

[image: Map Options - Layer Selector]

In this case, *Layer 1* is a point layer, which is turned on, while *Layer 2* is an underlying polygon layer, which is turned off so that the basemap is visible for context.

Just to be clear, activating this option means that any user seeing this map through a shared link or embed on a website will be able to toggle the layers on/off.

Also note that toggling a layer will also toggle on/off **its legend**, if you have added one to the map.